# controls not recognized

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a curved line and define the coordinates relative to previous nodes I have used (instead of absolute coordinates which works fine). This is what I have so far but it gives the following error:

Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function 'r1' (in 'r1.west')

why can I not use the name of the node here? And more importantly how can I solve it? I have added a picture of what I am trying to achieve in case it is not clear with my description

[image]

code so far (error at last line):

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks,shapes,shapes.symbols,arrows,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

% Start the picture
\begin{tikzpicture}%
[%
    >=stealth',                   %Define standard arrow tip
    start chain=going below,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
    node distance=1cm and 1cm, % Global setup of box spacing
    every join/.style={-, draw},   % Default linetype for connecting boxes
]

\tikzset{
  reservoir/.style={draw, rectangle,on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
  % coord node style is used for placing corners of connecting lines
  coord/.style={coordinate, on chain, on grid},
}

\tikzstyle{myarrows}=[line width=1mm,draw,-triangle 45,postaction={draw, line width=3mm, shorten >=4mm, -}]

% Start by placing the nodes
\node [reservoir,rotate=45, text width=2.5cm] (r1) {1};
\node [reservoir,rotate=20, text width= 1cm,right=0.5cm of r1.east] (r2) {2};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=12pt}]([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=-0.2cm]r2.east)--([xshift=0.2cm,yshift=-0.2cm]r1.west);

\node [reservoir,rotate=-30, text width= 2cm,right=0.5cm of r2.east] (r3) {3};
\node [reservoir,rotate=15, text width= 3.5cm,right=0.5cm of r3.east] (r4) {4};
\draw [decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=12pt}]([yshift=-1.3cm]r4.east)--([yshift=-1.3cm]r3.west) node [midway, anchor=north,yshift=-1cm]{Rainfall-runoff link 2};

% add connection lines
\draw (r1.east) -- (r2.west);
\draw (r2.east) -- (r3.west);
\draw (r3.east) -- (r4.west);

% add river curved line
\node [coord, above=1cm of r1.west] (b1)  {};
\node [coord, above=1cm of r3.west] (b2)  {};
\node [coord, above=1cm of r4.west] (b3)  {};
\node [coord, above=1cm of r4.east] (b4)  {};
\draw ([yshift=1cm]r1.west,[yshift=1cm]r1.west) .. controls ([yshift=1cm]r3.west,[yshift=1cm]r3.west) and ([yshift=1cm]r4.west,[yshift=1cm]r4.west) .. ([yshift=1cm]r4.east,[yshift=1cm]r4.east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `r1.west` is not just an x-coordinate or y-coordinate. It has both an x and y coordinate. So remove the duplication.  Instead of `([yshift=1cm]r1.west,[yshift=1cm]r1.west)`, just use `([yshift=1cm]r1.west)`. Similarly for the others.

Comment: great, thanks! no error anymore although it does not give the expected curvature at least I can start working on it further. Cannot believe how simple it was considering how much time I have lost on this. Still have a lot to learn! Which I knew latex sooner (not one month before my dissertation has to be submitted)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved in the comments.